# displaying HTML content on TextView

Tags: android, html, kotlin

i am displaying HTML content on TextView using HtmlCompat.fromHtml it is working fine but i faced an issues with color style for an inner span i takes the color for the parent span only ,
for this code it display all the lines as green which is the parent span color :

```
"<p><span style=\"color: #2dc26b;\">sdasdasdadad<br /><br /><br /><br /><span style=\"color: #000000;\">sadsadkaksjdaosjdlkasjd<br /><br /><br /><span style=\"color: #e03e2d;\">asdasdasdasdasdasd<br /><br /><br /><br /><span style=\"color: #2dc26b;\">sadsdasdasdasd</span></span></span></span></p>"
```

for below code it works fine:

```
"<p><span style=\"color: #2dc26b;\">green line</span></p>\n<p><span style=\"color: #e03e2d;\">red line&nbsp;</span></p>\n<p><span style=\"color: #236fa1;\">blue line</span></p>\n<p><span style=\"color: #e03e2d; background-color: #236fa1;\">blue bg red colr</span></p>",
```